Key fob detection issues
I'm driving a 2014 Nissan Pathfinder with keyless entry/remote start.
I know that technology doesn't last forever but have recently been having trouble with the car accepting my key fobs. The buttons on the fobs themselves work fine, to lock/unlock the doors, open/close the liftgate, or remote start the vehicle.
The ability to use the keyless entry/exit buttons and the START/STOP button has started to become intermittent. I've got two fobs that both came with the vehicle when it was purchased. When I started having issues with the fob I normally, I tried replacing batteries (in both fobs) and eventually switched to the less-used fob. It seemed to get better for a few weeks, but it's acting up again.
Occasionally when I try to press the ignition button, the display shows the message "Invalid Key ID" and the car won't start. So far I've been able to override it by touching the fob to the START/STOP button or using the buttons on the fob to lock/unlock the car, but I'm afraid It will finally fail completely and leave me stranded.
At first I thought it was just an old key fob being a problem, but now I'm afraid it's going to be an expensive sensor in the vehicle. Has anybody else had this issue, and can you share how you were able to resolve it?

Does this help? Factory service manual;  https://procarmanuals.com/pdf-online-nissan-pathfinder-2014-factory-service-manual/
